# Compare two Dictionary Key Values

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

```
Roles_dict1 = {'CEO':1,'CTO':2,'Devops':3}
User_list = {'Jhon':'CEO','MATEW':'Devops','Bill':'CTO'}

for key in Roles_dict1.keys():
            Z = [b for b in Roles_dict1.keys() if any(b in a for a in User_list.values())]
print(Z)
```

I'm trying to print **Z** in the order of Roles_dict1

**I'm getting this following as output**

['CEO', 'CTO', 'Devops']

**Expected output**

```
{'Jhon':'CEO','Bill':'CTO','MATEW':'Devops'}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You do `Z = [b for b in Roles_dict1.keys() if any(b in a for a in User_list.values())]` inside a loop, but in each iteration `Z`'s value overrides its value from the previous iteration, and anyhow they are all the same, since you never use `key`. Try to take it from here.

Comment: If you want to get a dictionary, don't use a list comprehension. List comprehensions create lists, not dictionaries.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Are you saying use a "dictionary comprehension" rather than a "list comprehension" or are you suggesting dictionaries cannot be constructed by comprehensions?

Comment: @JonSG the former (or any other way to create a dictionary)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to simply take the `items()` of your list then sort them using the values in roles.

```py
Roles_dict1 = {'CEO':1,'CTO':2,'Devops':3}
User_list = {'Jhon':'CEO','MATEW':'Devops','Bill':'CTO'}
user_list_items = sorted(User_list.items(), key=lambda item: Roles_dict1[item[1]])
print(dict(user_list_items))
```

This will give you:

```
{'Jhon': 'CEO', 'Bill': 'CTO', 'MATEW': 'Devops'}
```

If you don't see this you might have an older version of python and in that case, you might looks at `collections.OrderedDict()` or just leave things as a list of items.

Comment: That's interesting, good to know that dictionaries are now ordered (as of 3.7?). Does that make OrderedDict redundant in the newer version?

Comment: Yes, I think it does :-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the first dict for the desired output, as it is equal to `User_list`.

Comment: Based on the first dict i'm trying to get the output ...... the expected output need to be compared with values of user_list and key of Roles_dict

Comment: You cannot do that, because where would you get the names from, if you don't have the second dict available? If you have it available, why re-calculate it? This doesn't make sense in any way.

Comment: because the output need to be {'Jhon':'CEO','Bill':'CTO','MATEW':'Devops'} 

for this get i need to calculate according to the first dict ......  the value of second dict is 

{'Jhon':'CEO','MATEW':'Devops','Bill':'CTO'}

Comment: @VarunKumar There is no ordering in dictionaries I believe. I think you cannot access dictionary elements by index in the same way you access lists.

Comment: Exactly. Compare both dicts in python. They're equal.